# Invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it error trying to click and insert a date on a dropdown-toggle using Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm trying to click on this calendar and insert a date automatically using selenium, but I got the error below:

> invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to
>   clear it.

**HTML snippet**

```
<a id="enddate-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="">
                <p class="custom-datepickers__date-prefix ng-binding">To:</p>
                <!-- ngIf: displayEndDate -->
                <!-- ngIf: !displayEndDate --><div ng-if="!displayEndDate" class="custom-datepickers__no-date ng-scope"></div><!-- end ngIf: !displayEndDate -->
</a>
```

**Code snippet**

```
myclass.SetDateByXpath("//*[@id=\"enddate-dropdown\"]/p", myclass.GetDate("yyyy/MM/dd", mydate));

public void SetDateByXpath(String element, String value)
    {
        WebElement webElement = ExplicitWaitOnElement(By.xpath(element));       
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",webElement);
        webElement.clear();
        webElement.sendKeys(value);
    }
```

If I set the date manually, this is the HTML:

```
<a id="enddate-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="">
                <p class="custom-datepickers__date-prefix ng-binding">To:</p>
                <!-- ngIf: displayEndDate --><p ng-if="displayEndDate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">2019/11/21</p><!-- end ngIf: displayEndDate -->
                <!-- ngIf: !displayEndDate -->
</a>
```

Probably the website changed, but now I don't know how can I set this value. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you check if it is inside iframe? it would be better if you can share url if it is sharable?

Comment: There is no iframe in this website. I'm afraid I can't share it. Thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Any reason to cancel the bounty?

Comment: erm, it's a mistake. OP requested it but I shouldn't have accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

...implies that the element identified was not in a **user-editable** state to invoke `clear()` method.

---

To insert a date with in a dropdown-toggle with an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element there are two approaches:

- Either you can `click()` on the calendar and insert a date using `sendKeys()`
- Or you can use `executeScript()` to invoke `removeAttribute()` the **readonly** attribute.

---

However, as per the HTML you have shared it seems the element which gets populated with the date string i.e. **2019/11/21** is not readily available within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). So we can infer that the following element gets added to the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as a result of interaction with other *WebElements* which is as follows:

```
<p ng-if="displayEndDate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">2019/11/21</p>
```

Hence the best approach would be,

- First to invoke `click()` on the element readily available within the HTML inducing *WebDriverWait*.
- Next to invoke `sendKeys()` on the newly created element *WebDriverWait*.
- Code Block:

  ```
  //element -> myclass.SetDateByXpath("//a[@class='dropdown-toggle' and @id='enddate-dropdown']"
  // observe the change in the ^^^ xpath ^^^
  //value -> myclass.GetDate("yyyy/MM/dd", mydate));

  public void SetDateByXpath(String element, String value)
  {
      WebElement webElement = ExplicitWaitOnElement(By.xpath(element));       
      webElement.click();
      WebElement webElement_new = ExplicitWaitOnElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-toggle' and @id='enddate-dropdown']//p[@class='ng-binding ng-scope' and @ng-if='displayEndDate']"));
      webElement_new.clear();
      webElement_new.sendKeys(value);
  }
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [InvalidElementStateException invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it" error while sending text with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572475/invalidelementstateexception-invalid-element-state-element-must-be-user-editabl/59575234#59575234)

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing your error is being thrown at the lines:

```
webElement.clear();
webElement.sendKeys(value)
```

We can try to work around that by setting values through Javascript instead:

```
// updated selector for webElement to grab the p element which contains the date string
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"enddate-dropdown\"]/p[@ng-if='displayEndDate']"));

// try setting inner HTML which is the text inside the p
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHtml = '" + value + "';", webElement)

// alternative option is to try setting value instead
// ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = '" + value + "';", webElement)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christine, you are right, those lines are responsible for trigger the error. I've replaced the code using your Javascript, but I didn't have success setting the date in that field.

Comment: I noticed your XPath `//*[@id=\"enddate-dropdown\"]/div/input` is searching for an `input` element, but I don't see that element in the HTML snippet you provided. Could you include that too, so I can get a full idea of what this date picker looks like?

Comment: Ohh, it was a typo, the correct XPath is `"//*[@id=\"startdate-dropdown\"]/p"`. I'm gonna edit the post. But still stuck

Comment: Also, I edit the post putting the HTML after I set the date manually. Maybe it can help.

Comment: What happens if you run `.click()` on `//a[@id='enddate-dropdown']`? Is there a calendar popup to let you pick values? I also updated my answer to set `innerHtml` instead of `value` on the element -- it's worth trying that out too.

Comment: Yes, it is a calendar. I changed my code but still stuck...this is how the HTML looks after running your code:

```<a id="enddate-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="">
                <p class="custom-datepickers__date-prefix ng-binding">To:</p>
                <!-- ngIf: displayEndDate -->
                <!-- ngIf: !displayEndDate --><div ng-if="!displayEndDate" class="custom-datepickers__no-date ng-scope"></div><!-- end ngIf: !displayEndDate -->
            </a>```

Comment: I did just realize something -- `//*[@id=\"enddate-dropdown\"]/p` is probably returning the first `p` element under your `a` element, which is not the correct `p` that is getting set with the date. I've updated my answer to try a different selector.

Comment: Got this error now:
`Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id="enddate-dropdown"]/p[@ng-if='displayEndDate']`
But yeah, the xpath looks wrong, missing the other p tag and ng-if.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202432/discussion-between-pankwood-and-christine).