# InvalidElementStateException invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it" error while sending text with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an input HTML element like this in Django

```html
<input id="id" type="number" maxlength="50">
```

When I want to find and clear it

```py
elm_input = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, elm_id)))
elm_input.clear()
elm_input.send_keys(value)
```

It's got error `InvalidElementStateException`

```
InvalidElementStateException invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it"
```

We cannot send key clear because selenium know `CLEAR` or `DELETE` Keys is an Charactics Keys not an Number Keys, It's don't send Keys to element input. So how can I we fix it, I had try `ActionChains` but It's not working with as well

Comment: I am sure the `elm_input` that you got is not an input type field. Check the ID, if it's pointing to the input element.

Comment: It's absolutely correct, because If I remove line `elm_input.clear()` 
I will work well, But I want to clear value of the input

Comment: have you tried clicking on it before clear?

Comment: Yes, I had try click but in some case, All of my input not get correct element location. And It's also get error
So I remove line click

Comment: Meaning you are not pointing to the right input field. It's hard to provide reason, without having either the url to the page or the source code.

Comment: No, this error show that this input is just allowed for typing number, Not for charactics. I think so :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
InvalidElementStateException invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it"
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to clear the existing contents of the element.

---

A bit more of the outerHTML of the element would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However you need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- While sending a *character sequence* instead of using `presence_of_element_located()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- Ensure the *Locator Strategy* uniquely identifies the *WebElement* and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    elm_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#id[type='number'][maxlength='50']")))
    elm_input.clear()
    elm_input.send_keys("1234567890")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    elm_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='id' and @type='number'][@maxlength='50']")))
    elm_input.clear()
    elm_input.send_keys("1234567890")
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it error trying to click and insert a date on a dropdown-toggle using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881440/invalid-element-state-element-must-be-user-editable-in-order-to-clear-it-error/58997476#58997476)